# Why is the class type in mapply(as.POSIXct , myCSV) not recognised as POSIX type?

Tags: r, posixct, mapply

I have a list of dates in character/string format and I need to read them as `POSIXct` dates.

```
>  x  <- as.POSIXct("95-11-22" , format="%y-%m-%d")             #should equal myParsedDates[1]
> typeof(x)
[1] "double"
> class(x)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"                                      #Member of POSIXct class

> myDates <- c("95-11-22", "95-11-23", "95-12-25")
> myParsedDates <- mapply(function(x){as.POSIXct(x, format="%y-%m-%d")}   ,   myDates)
> typeof(myParsedDates[1])
[1] "double"
> class(myParsedDates[1])
[1] "numeric"                                               #Not a member of POSIXct 

> x                              #The class information is retained
[1] "1995-11-22 AWST"
> myParsedDates[1]               #The class information is lost
 95-11-22 
816969600
```

Why, when `mapply` is called on the list, does the `POSIXct` class information get lost? How can it be retained?

Comment: The answer *might* be because `mapply` tries to coerce the datatype into the existing vector type. 
A solution I found is to apply `as.POSIXct` to the vector (It seems that `as.POSIXct` is ad-hoc polymorphic, applicable to both 0 and some 1-dimensional objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in essence a more complicated version of the (known, documented, still sad) mis-feature of S3 class attributes dropping when concatenating vectors.

I am using `as.Date()` here (and a string that parses without format), but it is the same with `as.POSIXct()`.

First, what works:

```
> as.Date("2022-01-16")
[1] "2022-01-16"
> as.Date("2022-01-16")
[1] "2022-01-16"
>
```

Second, what doesn't _because `sapply` constructs a vector:

```
> sapply(c("2022-01-16", "2022-01-17"), as.Date)
2022-01-16 2022-01-17 
     19008      19009 
> class(sapply(c("2022-01-16", "2022-01-17"), as.Date))
[1] "numeric"
>
```

The actual *names* comes back because `sapply` is kind to use them as label, but the result is not longer a `Date` object.  For completeness, same with `as.POSIXct`:

```
> as.POSIXct("2022-01-16")
[1] "2022-01-16 CST"
> class(as.POSIXct("2022-01-16"))
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> class(sapply(c("2022-01-16", "2022-01-17"), as.POSIXct))
[1] "numeric"
>
```

It works via `lapply` and `do.call()`:

```
> do.call(c, lapply(c("2022-01-16", "2022-01-17"), as.Date))
[1] "2022-01-16" "2022-01-17"
> class(do.call(c, lapply(c("2022-01-16", "2022-01-17"), as.Date)))
[1] "Date"
>
```

It also works if you make the objects part of a `data.frame` and stack the `data.frame` rows, and/or if you inject them into pre-allocated vectors, or ... if one simply calls vectorised:

```
> as.Date(c("2022-01-16", "2022-01-17"))
[1] "2022-01-16" "2022-01-17"
> class(as.Date(c("2022-01-16", "2022-01-17")))
[1] "Date"
>
```

which is of course not always possible.